# casting and summing duration values

Tags: mysql

All, I have a MySQL table named duration which contains names and total duration time for separate locations visited over one day. I need to total the times and show them for each person (in hours, mins, seconds format). I am struggling with the correct SQL code (prefer not to use a stored procedure). The Duration column is TIME datatype.

```
Name    Duration

Fred    04:00:20
John    12:39:10
Jack    03:59:20
Stacy   19:17:34
Stacy   03:39:00
John    04:20:30
Jack    00:29:17
John    03:23:50
Fred    300:17:29
```

I have used the following sql (from Akshay Hegde)

select name, SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( time_to_sec( duration ) ) ) 
from duration 
group by name;

Which works fine for total durations less than 24 hours (i.e. Jack's total duration 04:28:37, Stacy's total duration 22:56:34) but fails for durations greater than 24 hours.

Sadly the sql works fine in MySQL Workbench (even with 300 hours but not within java where the result is "bad format for time '300 in column etc).

I believe I need to cast Duration as a char and then somehow sum on that.

Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like a problem with the Java MySQL API you're using, it doesn't understand times larger than 24 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your Java API doesn't understand times larger than 24 hours, try converting to a string.

```
select name, CAST(SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( time_to_sec( duration ) ) ) AS CHAR) AS total_time
from duration 
group by name;
```